# Como obter um token da API do Facebook?

Tags: json, facebook, api, http, request

Para entender melhor o funcionamento da API do Facebook, eu gostaria de criar uma requisição para realizar login e obter um token. Porém só acho explicações através da SDK ou do API explore, localizado no próprio site do Facebook na área de desenvolvimento.

Alguém poderia ensinar como fazer o login e obter o token apenas via requisições manuais? E também, se possível, fazer um exemplo?